# Basic Php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I hope you can help me!

I have the following php file which I include it from another php file.

"Connect ()" connects to the database.
"Query ()" makes a query to the database
"Disconnect" disconnect with the database.

```
function consulta($conexion, $sql){

        // Realizar una consulta SQL
        if (!$resultado = $conexion->query($sql)) {
            // La consulta falló. 
            $error = "Lo sentimos, la consulta fall&oacute;.";

            /*
            echo "Error: La ejecución de la consulta falló debido a: \n";
            echo "Query: " . $sql . "\n";
            echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->errno . "\n";
            echo "Error: " . $mysqli->error . "\n";
            exit;
            */

            return false;

        } else {
                // Consulta exitosa.. pero... tenemos resultados?
                if ($resultado->num_rows !== 0) {
                    return $resultado->num_rows;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }

            }
    }
```

.................
The file complete (funciones_mysql.php) is:

```
<?php

function conectardb($host, $usuario, $pass, $db){

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $pass, $db);

        if ($mysqli->connect_errno){
            // La conexión falló

            $error= "Error al conectar con la base de datos.";

            /*
            echo "Error: Fallo al conectarse a MySQL debido a: \n";
            echo "Errno: " . $mysqli->connect_errno . "\n";
            echo "Error: " . $mysqli->connect_error . "\n";
            */
            //return false;
        } 

        return $mysqli;
} //fin funcion conectar



function consulta($conexion, $sql){

        // Realizar una consulta SQL
        if (!$resultado = $conexion->query($sql)) {
            // La consulta falló. 
            $error = "Lo sentimos, la consulta fall&oacute;.";

            return false;

        } else {
                // Consulta exitosa.. pero... tenemos resultados?
                if ($resultado->num_rows !== 0) {
                    return $resultado->num_rows;
                } else {
                    return true;
                }

            }
    }


function desconectardb($mysqli){
        $mysqli->close();
    }


?>
```

And the other php file is: (registracion.php)

```
<?php
include('funciones_mysql.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //Si el submit fue presionado..

    /*
    if (empty($_POST['nombre']) || empty($_POST['apellido']) || empty($_POST['dni']) || empty($_POST['mail']) || empty($_POST['sexo']) || empty($_POST['fecha'])) { //Si algun campo esta vacio..
        $error = "Hay campos vacios";
    }
    else
    {
    */
        //Si el usuario ingresó algun dato...
        // Obtner datos
        $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
        $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];
        $dni=$_POST['dni'];
        $mail=$_POST['mail'];
        $sexo=$_POST['sexo'];
        $fecha_nac=$_POST['fecha'];

        // Conectarse a y seleccionar una base de datos de MySQL llamada tp5
        // Nombre de host: 127.0.0.1, usuario, contraseña, bd: tp5

        if(!$conexion = conectardb('127.0.0.1','root','','tp5')){
            $error="Error al conectar";
            } else {
                    // Realizar una consulta SQL
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `cliente` (`Id`, `nombre`, `apellido`, `dni`, `mail`, `sexo`, `fecha_nac`) VALUES (NULL, '$nombre', '$apellido', '$dni', '$mail', '$sexo', '$fecha_nac')";

                    if(!$resultado = consulta($conexion, $sql)){
                        $error = "Error en la consulta";
                    } else {
                            $mensaje = "Registro insertado ok";
                            }

                    desconectardb($conexion);

                }
    //}
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registracion</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Registrar un usuario.. </h1>
        <div id="login">
            <form action="" method="post">

                <input name="nombre" placeholder="nombre" type="text">

                <input name="apellido" placeholder="apellido" type="text">

                <input name="dni" placeholder="dni" type="text">

                <input name="mail" placeholder="mail" type="text">

                <input name="sexo" placeholder="sexo" type="text">

                <input name="fecha" placeholder="fecha" type="date">

                <input name="submit" type="submit" value=" OK ">
                <span><?php echo $error . "<br>" . $mensaje; ?></span>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

And he tells me an error when I try to enter data into the form, pulse "OK" and ...

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ TP6 \ funciones_mysql.php on line 44

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ TP6 \ funciones_mysql.php on line 45

```
LINE 44:   if ($resultado->num_rows !== 0) {
LINE 45:                    return $resultado->num_rows;
```

I can not find the problem but certainly something I'm doing wrong, I hope you 
can help me!

Thank you

Comment: In many cases a sql query fails so that `false` is return instead of a result set. Whats the content of the lines 44/45 in `funciones_mysql.php`?

Comment: @mapek
LINE 44:   if ($resultado->num_rows !== 0) {
LINE 45:     return $resultado->num_rows;